# Gridview: Change Button Text and link on Page load

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Gurus,

I have a gridview with the template field button and I want to change text on the button on the user type on page load.

I am trying to get the button from Gridview to change the text and link but the control  always return null. It will be really helpful to understand how to change the text and link on page load.

> TryCast(row.Cells(0).Controls(0).FindControl("idAppearButton"),
>   Button)

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            If Trim(Request.QueryString("Msg")) <> "" Then
                If InStr(Request.QueryString("Msg"), "<") > 0 Then
                    Response.Write(Mid(Request.QueryString("Msg"), 1, InStr(Request.QueryString("Msg"), "<")))
                Else
                    Response.Write(Request.QueryString("Msg"))
                End If
            End If
            If Page.IsPostBack = False Then
                Dim sSeries As String

                sSeries = "Aim NBDE Part 1"

                Dim o_cmd As SqlCommand
                Dim o_reader As SqlDataReader
                o_Con = New SqlConnection(GlobalVarC.DataS)
                o_Con.Open()

                Dim ds As New Data.DataSet
                Dim da As SqlDataAdapter

                Dim ExamId As String
                S_Sql = "SELECT SNo from Exam_Ser where Series='" & sSeries.ToString & "'"
                o_cmd = New SqlCommand(S_Sql, o_Con)
                o_reader = o_cmd.ExecuteReader
                ExamId = ""
                Dim ExamIdTmp As String
                While o_reader.Read
                    If ExamId.Equals("") Then
                        ExamId = ExamId + "SNo = "
                    Else
                        ExamId = ExamId + " OR SNo = "
                    End If
                    ExamIdTmp = o_reader(0).ToString
                    ExamId = ExamId + ExamIdTmp
                    ExamId = ExamId + ""
                End While
                o_reader.Close()
                o_cmd.Dispose()

                S_Sql = "SELECT Name from Exam where " & ExamId.ToString

                da = New SqlDataAdapter(S_Sql, o_Con)
                da.Fill(ds)


                GridSubject.DataSource = ds
                GridSubject.DataBind()
                da.Dispose()
                ds.Dispose()
                o_Con.Close()

                For Each row As GridViewRow In GridSubject.Rows
                    Dim button As Button
                    'button = TryCast(row.Cells(0).Controls(0).FindControl("idAppearButton"), Button)
                    'button.Text = "Buy"
                Next

            End If

        End Sub



<asp:GridView ID="GridSubject" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="3" 
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridSubject_SelectedIndexChanged" BackColor="#CCCCCC"
                        BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
        Width="714px" GridLines="Horizontal"
                         >
                        <EditRowStyle Font-Names="Calibri" />
                        <EmptyDataRowStyle Font-Names="Calibri" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Names="Calibri" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" Font-Names="Calibri" />
                        <Columns >
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Exam Name">
                                <ItemStyle Width="140px" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Part 1</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Part 2</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="3">Part 1 &amp; 2</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                <ItemStyle Width="100px" HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="idAppearButton" runat="server" 
                                     CommandName="MYCOMMAND" Text="Appear">
                                    </asp:Button>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="ViewResults" Text="Results" >
                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Top"  />
                            </asp:ButtonField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Not Completed"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                        </Columns>
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#000000" Font-Names="Calibri" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" 
                            Font-Names="Cambria" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" HorizontalAlign="Right" 
                            Font-Names="Calibri" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />

<SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F4F4FD"></SortedAscendingCellStyle>

<SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#5A4C9D"></SortedAscendingHeaderStyle>

<SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D8D8F0"></SortedDescendingCellStyle>

<SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#3E3277"></SortedDescendingHeaderStyle>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `Row.FindControl(id)` to find the reference to the control. You cannot use `Cell.Text` if you use `TemplateFields`, that works only with `BoundFields`:

```
button = DirectCast(row.FindControl("idAppearButton"), Button)
```